# google maps polygon outline color vary when polygons overlap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, polygons

(I posted this in the google maps forum before I saw a specific one for the API.  oops)

I have a google maps webpage where I am trying to draw a lot of polygons. Currently using Google maps api v3.8 (Firefox 17.0.1 under Ubuntu 10).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.8&libraries=geometry&sensor=false" ></script>
```

I use ajax calls to create each a polygon using:

```
record.poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    strokeColor: lineColor,
    strokeOpacity: lineOpacity,
    strokeWeight: lineWidth,
    fillColor: lineColor,
    fillOpacity: fillOpacity
});
for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i += 2)
{
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(points[i + 1], points[i]);
    record.poly.getPath().push(point);
}
```

In this example, I created about 3400 polygons (color blue, width 2, line opacity 0.7, fill opacity 0.2) by calling:

```
record.poly.setMap(myMap);
```

when I am ready to display.

Then I created another roughly 3600 polygons in green (width 6, line opacity 0.7, fill opacity 0.2) by calling the same code.

The problem is what I see isn't consistent. I expected to see a lot of greenish-blue squares or a lot of blueish-greeen squares, depending on which the browser draws first. But I don't. I a see both greenish-blue and blueish-greeen.

I can't really link to my application, but this is what the map looks like when I zoom out:
http://itic.occinc.com/brian/gmap-boxes-full.png

and when you zoom in:
http://itic.occinc.com/brian/gmap-boxes-zoom.png

I don't really care too much if it is blue-green or green-blue when both are displayed, but I do need it to be consistent across the map.

At a high level, any ideas? Am I bumping against some sort of shape limit?

- B

Comment: I should have mentioned that the two areas match except for the horitzonal green line under the 'Egg Harbor City' label.

Comment: Are you plotting the exact same polygon locations but with different properties?

Comment: Yes, I am creating an editing function and one color represents the before and one represents the after.

Comment: Are you trying to highlight a street/road?  Right now your highlighting looks way to thick almost 4x what you would need from the images you posted.

Comment: I am not trying to higlight a road.  I am allowing a user to select a box that encompasses an area.  On color indicates what color they have previously selected (blue) and the other color shows the boxes during editing (green).

It appears that either the Google map javascript or my browser is randomly determine which created polygon to draw first.  Again, in the zoom'd image, there are both blue squares and green squares for each polygon.  some you can see the blue outline and some you can't.  I don't partically care which outline you see, but I do need it consistant for all the polgygons.